# how to keep a part of a cookbook from executing

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, chef-infra

I am a chef noob and am using chef-solo to manage several ElasticSearch nodes on Amazon. The basic recipe allow me to initialize an EBS disk and attach it. My question is, when updating the ES software (e.g. 0.20 to 0.90) with chef, how do I keep the existing data on the EBS disk from being reinitialized/formated? Is there a way to exclude a part of the recipe or databag without having to have copies of the json?

[See relevant attributes here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/c74375ff57b6ec0147936cb215c3e251713bd456/attributes/data.rb#L15)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put any conditionals or take any measures when your EBS has been already created, mounted, formatted, etc. The Elasticsearch Chef cookbook eg. formats the device `only_if` it isn't already formatted, see https://github.com/elasticsearch/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/master/recipes/data.rb#L11

Provided you keep the EBS volume attached to your instance, Chef doesn't touch it -- or definitely *shouldn't* touch it. If you'd see any other behaviour, please submit an [issue at Github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/cookbook-elasticsearch/issues).